# Is there a way to call a Go reusable template inside an if action?

Tags: go, go-templates

I would like to know if there is any way I could use the output from calling a reusable template inside an `if` conditional, e.g. something along the lines of this:

```
{{ define "test.tmpl" }}SomeExpectedValue{{ end }}
Header
{{/* here \/ */}}
{{- if eq (template "test.tmpl") "SomeExpectedValue" }}
The expected body: {{ template "test.tmpl" }}.
{{- else }}
Something else.
{{- end }}
Footer
```

Since a reusable template can be used easily throughout the body of a template via the `template` action, I was hoping I could also use it inside an `if` condition. So far, looking at the go template [docs](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template), I couldn't figure out a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of a template cannot be used as a value within a template. What you are looking for can be done using additional template functions that you pass to `template.Funcs` before evaluating the template. So, instead of writing a `test.tmpl`, write a Go function that returns a value, and call that function from your template.

Comment: For what it's worth, my template is in fact consumed by a framework (Prometheus in kubernetes), so I don't have direct access to the Go code that handles the template. I was looking for a solution that touches on the template code alone. Thanks for confirming the above though!